# Can I overload class by generic type in java like in C#?

Tags: java

```java
public class A<T>
{
    // do something
}
public class A<T, B>
{
    // do something
}
```

I just want to create a class that just contains value of every generic type. Like Tuple in C#:

```cs
Tuple<int> intContainer = new Tuple<int>(5);
Tuple<int, int> twoIntContainer = new Tuple<int, int>(5, 5);
Tuple<int, int, int> threeIntContainer = new Tuple<int, int, int>(5, 5, 5);
```

Comment: You can not (yet) have primitive generics in Java. `Tuple<Integer>` is possible, though. But you can not have a variable number of generics.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-misc/java-tuples/#:~:text=Java%20doesn't%20have%20any,of%20data%20types%20by%20design.

Comment: @Polygnome can you write it as answer? I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, you can not have primitive types as generic parameters, only reference types. Thus, you can not have `Tuple<int>` at all (at least not yet, thats in the works), but need to use `Tuple<Integer>`.

Furthermore, Java does not allow overloading a class, at all. You can not have two definitions for a class, thus you can not have the same class with a different amount of generic parameters.
You can subclass the class, though, and add more generic parameters to the subclass, with all the pros and cons that has.

With Java 14, we got nominal tuples in the form of Records as a preview feature ([2nd preview in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384)). Thus, creating ad-hoc data structures that can hold the required elements has become much easier, greatly reducing the demand for general-purpose tuple types.

Related reading:

- [Data Classes and Sealed Types for Java](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/datum_3.html)